# How to determine if two bounding boxes collide during a transformation

Tags: game-engine, game-physics, bounding-box

I have been looking into bounding boxes, specifically AABB, and I understand them for the most part. I know how to figure out if two BBs are colliding. What I don't understand is how to tell if they collide during a transformation.

Say I have two bounding boxes. One of them moves from one frame to the next. It moves along a path that would intersect with the other but because the transformation is larger than the size of the stationary box, it is not colliding before or after the transformation. What do I have to do to determine if the two boxes would collide if the increments of movement were small enough?

Edit:  I just found [this](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/swept-aabb-collision-detection-and-response-r3084). I'll read it and see if it is what I am looking for.

Comment: Does this refer to 2D or 3D? And is it valid to assume that "transformation" **only** refers to a *translation* (and not to a rotation or so)?

Comment: @Marco13 Either 2d or 3d. If someone can explain 2d then I can figure out 3d.  And they are axis aligned, so rotations are irrelevant.

Comment: Can you please clarify what an AABB is.

Comment: @S.Pinkus Axis aligned bounding box. As opposed to oriented bounding boxes, or some other form of collision detection.

Comment: The step from 2D to 3D is probably not trivial. However, for 2D, the article that you linked to in your "edit" seems to point in the right direction. You might consider either deleting this question, or, preferably, writing a nice answer on your own.

Comment: @Marco13 I was planning on writing a nice answer when I got there myself. But I'm still trying to wrap my head around the article.